# Convert a raster with one band into a raster with RVB bands on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, convert

So yesterday i downloaded a raster tile on a WMS server and exported it with Grass. I get a raster with 3 bands, i treat with the Semi automatic classification Plugin in QGIS and it works perfectly. But today i realized that said raster didn't cover the whole area i'm working on right now, i download the raster again, from the SAME source with the SAME settings (i checked twice) i export it using GRASS again and when i try to resample said raster with SCP it doesn't recognize it. I don't uderstand why imediatly up until i check the bands and realize that now, the raster is on only one classified band and not on RVB. Since the raster took hours to download i would like to know if i could convert this panchromatic tile into an RVB one and, if their is no simple way, how to force the r.in.wms function to take RVB rasters when it is avaible.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Translate** tool which allows you to convert input rasters into RGB by setting the `Expand` option and selecting `RGB`.

You can find the tool from the menu bar:

*Raster > Conversion > Translate*